# unknown (x:name) in xamarin while creating the event of a picker

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

when i use the indicator (x:name )in file.xaml.cs , its shown that it is unknow

however when i did another picker in other exercice , it worked normally and i created the events on well.

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="viewRapport" ItemsSource="{Binding Rapports}" 
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
          ItemTapped="list_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding AmountReimbursed}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                                <Picker x:Name="ListR" Title="plus" Grid.Column="4" SelectedIndexChanged="ListRappor_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                                        <x:String>Modifier</x:String>
                                        <x:String>Supprimer</x:String>
                                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                                </Picker>
                            </Grid>           
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and this is the event of the picker

```
  private void ListRappor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     var choix=ListR.Items[ListR.SelectedIndex];
      switch(choix){
      }
    }
```

to better understand the problem, "ListR" is unkown in the event .

Comment: You can't use `x:Name` for elements that are inside of templates.  The `sender` argument of the event handler will be a reference to your Picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not accessible in this context because it's defined in the `DataTemplate`. If you want to access this `Picker` in the event handler you can access it by using sender parameter.

Here is an example:

```
private void ListRappor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var ListR = sender as Picker;
  var choix=ListR.Items[ListR.SelectedIndex];
  switch(choix){
  }
}
```